# How to print out a byte variable in Rust

Tags: rust

I am currently working on a cryptography project and I am new to Rust, and I am pretty confused on how to print out these public and private keys right now.

**Goal**: Print out the private and public key so I can see it.

Rust Code

```
pub use pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::{
    public_key_bytes as public_key_bytes,
    secret_key_bytes as secret_key_bytes, 
    signature_bytes as signature_bytes,
    verify_detached_signature as verify_detached_signature,
    detached_sign as detached_sign,
    keypair as keypair,
    open as open,
    sign as sign,
};

fn main () {
    let (public_key, private_key) = keypair();
    // Print variable here...
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "project"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
pqcrypto-dilithium = "0.4.5"
```

Error

```
    error[E0277]: `pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::PublicKey` doesn't implement `Debug`
  --> src\main.rs:14:23
   |
14 |     println!("{:#?}", public_key)
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ `pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::PublicKey` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `pqcrypto_dilithium::dilithium5::PublicKey`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Run this code using `cargo run`

Answer (score 1):

In order to print an instance of any type with the `{:?}` formatting placeholder, the type has to implement the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) trait. This trait tells rust how to display the contents of the instance.

Neither [`PublicKey`](https://docs.rs/pqcrypto-dilithium/0.4.5/pqcrypto_dilithium/dilithium5/struct.PublicKey.html) nor [`SecretKey`](https://docs.rs/pqcrypto-dilithium/0.4.5/pqcrypto_dilithium/dilithium5/struct.SecretKey.html) types directly implement `Debug`. However, both of them have methods that expose slices of `u8` containing the keys: the [`as_bytes`](https://docs.rs/pqcrypto-traits/0.3.4/pqcrypto_traits/sign/trait.PublicKey.html#tymethod.as_bytes) method.

Note that the `as_bytes()` method is part of a trait, `pqcrypto_traits::sign::PublicKey`. In order to use trait methods you need to have the trait in scope, so you have to `use` it in your source file.

Slices [implement `Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-Debug) as long as the slice elements implement `Debug`, which [`u8` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u8.html#impl-Debug), so you can print a `u8` slice.

```
use pqcrypto_traits::sign::PublicKey;

//...

println!("Public key: {:#?}", public_key.as_bytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was the following

1. Adding `pqcrypto-traits = "0.3.4" to Cargo.toml`, and saving the .toml file.
2. Using `pub use pqcrypto_traits::sign::PublicKey;`, and saving the .rs file.

If you get problems with `Sha256::new()`, put `pub use pqcrypto_traits::sign::PublicKey;` under that line. This is what worked for me.